# nodeschool:learnyoumongo "FIND" lesson fails before I write anything - config?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Currently the only thing I have in my file is the following:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/learnyoumongo';
console.log(mongo);
```

When I run the verify command, I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/learnyoumongo/exercises/find/exercise.js:37
db.collection('parrots').remove({}, function(err) {
^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined
at Exercise.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/learnyoumongo/exercises/find/exercise.js:37:5)
at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/learnyoumongo/node_modules/workshopper-exercise/exercise.js:260:17)
at Exercise.end (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/learnyoumongo/node_modules/workshopper-exercise/exercise.js:266:5)
at Workshopper.end (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/learnyoumongo/node_modules/workshopper/workshopper.js:191:12)
at Workshopper.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/learnyoumongo/node_modules/workshopper/workshopper.js:323:19)
at Exercise.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/learnyoumongo/node_modules/workshopper-exercise/exercise.js:149:14)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/learnyoumongo/node_modules/workshopper-exercise/exercise.js:136:16
at Exercise.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/learnyoumongo/node_modules/workshopper-exercise/filecheck.js:10:14)
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
```

When I took a look at the exercises.js file, I see the error is pointing to the .addCleanup function and the db it is trying to close is undefined.

This seems like a connection/configuration error, but I passed the first two modules. Can anyone help?

## Update

This is definitely a connection error. The previous scenario was created using the command in the workshop module `mongod --port 27017 --dbpath=./data`, however when I opened a new terminal tab and just ran `mongo` without any arguments, the verify command actually output the "Actual/Expected" evaluation and module results.

To the user who asked for the rest of the script, please understand if you are unfamiliar with nodeschool that this is an entire repository with module based automated/interactive tutorials, so this is not all of the code. In any case, here is what you requested:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient
  , exercise = require('workshopper-exercise')()
  , filecheck = require('workshopper-exercise/filecheck')
  , execute = require('workshopper-exercise/execute')
  , comparestdout = require('workshopper-exercise/comparestdout')

exercise = filecheck(exercise)

exercise = execute(exercise)

exercise = comparestdout(exercise)

var db, url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/learnyoumongo'

exercise.addSetup(function(mode, cb) {
  var self = this
  this.submissionArgs = [3]
  this.solutionArgs = [3]
  mongo.connect(url, function(err, _db) {
    if (err) return cb(err)
    db = _db
    col = db.collection('parrots')
    col.insert([{
      name: 'Fred'
    , age: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Jane'
    , age: 3
    }, {
      name: 'Jenny'
    , age: 10
    }], cb)
  })
})

exercise.addCleanup(function(mode, pass, cb) {
  db.collection('parrots').remove({}, function(err) {
    if (err) return cb(err)
    db.close()
    cb()
   })
})

module.exports = exercise
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that should be:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/learnyoumongo', function(err, db) {
   console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: what's this? `db.collection('parrots').remove({}, function(err) {`that isn't in your code, please add the full code

Answer (score 0):

There was definitely a connection problem. I'm not sure exactly where the bug was, but I reloaded learnyoumongo and reinstalled a couple of node packages. When I did that I had to go back and change permissions on the data directory again.

My recommendation if anyone else faces strange config errors, is to try to reinstall. Then when you connect, it doesn't hurt to re-verify the CONNECT module to make sure you have a good connection when you start your work space.